# What is "i" in a CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

When I right-click to inspect a "Choose File" button in an `input` of type `file`, Google Chrome's User Agent Stylesheet shows

```
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button
```

as a CSS chunk that selects that element. What is the `i` in the above?

By the way, this question relates to my trying to style the "Choose File" button. Does `input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button` select the "Choose File" button?

[image]

Comment: Could we please see an example of where this happens?

Comment: This isn't HTML. Some context please.

Comment: @jaunt I've added a screenshot for you to see

Comment: Knew I'd seen this before somewhere. :)

Comment: "Does `input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button` select the 'Choose File' button?" Yes; the `input[type="file" i]` portion matches the entire file picker control (including the label), while the `::-webkit-file-upload-button` targets the button component of the control itself, which WebKit exposes to CSS as a non-standard pseudo-element.